# Two Spring apps each use jpa to control a single database

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Two Spring apps each use jpa to control a single database.
Each Spring app must use a single database.
Will spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update work properly?

Comment: why do you think `hibernate update` won't work `properly`?

Comment: Define "properly"?  do they have the same entities?  Are the common entities *always* the same?

Comment: @Taylor 
We have two servers. Both apps use the same database value    
1. admin spring app.
2. user interaction spring app.

Our two servers use the same database.
# member table
ㄴ id
ㄴ name

# phone table
ㄴ id
ㄴ name
ㄴ member_no


admin app, user interaction app will set up as follows. Is there a problem?  
"spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update"

Comment: OP asks for database concurrency. It's a smart question. Simple answer. No. Suppose the two applications need to add a row to a given table. Both of them read the table, find out that the last generated id is 4, now both of them try to add a row. Which one will take into effect? A better alternative is to create a simple micro service that handle access to database

Comment: create a Jar of Pojo's and use commmon among both projects, if any change will be consistent among your Spring app

Comment: Thank you for answer.
Would it be okay if each of our Spring apps has different table areas for insert, update, and delete?
If there is a problem, is there any device that does the same thing as Synchronized Java?

Comment: Is it a deadlock in a typical database?
Or is it a situation that can only be seen in jpa?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, having 2 applications using directly the same database is a poor design.

Here is a quote from [this sofware engineering answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/105786/should-i-use-one-database-per-application-or-share-a-single-database-amongst-mul)

> The more applications use the same database, the more likely it is
>   that you hit performance bottlenecks and that you can't easily scale
>   the load as desired. SQL Databases don't really scale. You can buy
>   bigger machines but they do not scale well in clusters!
>
> Maintenance and development costs can increase: Development is harder
>   if an application needs to use database structures which aren't suited
>   for the task at hand but have to be used as they are already present.
>   It's also likely that adjustments of one application will have side
>   effects on other applications ("why is there such an unecessary
>   trigger??!"/"We don't need that data anymore!"). It's already hard
>   with one database for a single application, when the developers
>   don't/can't know all the use-cases.
>
> Administration becomes harder: Which object belongs to which
>   application? Chaos rising. Where do I have to look for my data? Which
>   user is allowed to interact with which objects? What can I grant whom?
>
> Upgrading: You'll need a version that is the lowest common denominator
>   for all applications using it. That means that certain applications
>   won't be able to use powerful features. You'll have to stick with
>   older versions. It also increases development costs a bit.
>
> Concurrency: Can you really be sure that there're no chronological
>   dependencies between processes? What if one application modifies data
>   that is outdated or should've been altered by another application
>   first? What about different applications working on the same tables
>   concurrently?

What I would suggest to you is to create a service layer which will be responsible for dealing with database access. This service can then be accessed by differents ways (a REST webservice might be an option).

Answer (score 0):

@Vinod Bokare comment is correct, you must create jar of POJO's and use in both projects,

and @Heejeong Jang, It will be okay if each of our Spring apps has different table areas for insert, update, and delete.

Comment: Then you should considering have 2 different database schema